# How to read and write a HashMap to a file?

Tags: java, file, file-io, hashmap

I have the following **HashMap**:

```
HashMap<String,Object> fileObj = new HashMap<String,Object>();

ArrayList<String> cols = new ArrayList<String>();  
cols.add("a");  
cols.add("b");  
cols.add("c");  
fileObj.put("mylist",cols);
```

I write it to a file as follows:

```
File file = new File("temp");  
FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);  
ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);          
s.writeObject(fileObj);
s.flush();
```

Now I want to read this file back to a HashMap where the Object is an ArrayList.
If i simply do:

```
File file = new File("temp");  
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);  
ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);  
fileObj = (HashMap<String,Object>)s.readObject();         
s.close();
```

This does not give me the object in the format that I saved it in.
It returns a table with 15 null elements and the < mylist,[a,b,c] > pair at the 3rd element. I want it to return only one element with the values I had provided to it in the first place.
    //How can I read the same object back into a HashMap ?

OK So based on Cem's note: This is what seems to be the correct explanation:

**ObjectOutputStream serializes the objects (HashMap in this case) in whatever format that ObjectInputStream will understand to deserialize and does so generically for any Serializable object. 
If you want it to serialize in the format that you desire you should write your own serializer/deserializer.**

*In my case: I simply iterate through each of those elements in the HashMap when I read the Object back from the file and get the data and do whatever I want with it. (it enters the loop only at the point where there is data).*

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "does not give me the object in the format that I saved it"?  Provide some examples of what you're seeing and what you expect.

Comment: Why isn't your HashMap declared as `HashMap<String,List<String>>`?

Comment: +1 for HashMap<String,List<String>>

Comment: It returns a table with 15 null elements and the < mylist,[a,b,c] > pair at the 3rd element. I want it to return only one element with the values I had provided to it in the first place.

Comment: See, ObjectOutputStream serializes the objects (HashMap in this case) in whatever format that ObjectInputStream will understand to deserialize and does so generically for any Serializable object. If you want it to serialize in the format that you desire you should write your own serializer/deserializer.

Comment: What are the keys of the 15 null elements ? What is the result of fileObj.size() ?

Comment: How do you see the 15 null elements? If only the third has a key value pair, then the other values are empty - this means the hashmap contains only one element - the one you stored.

Comment: @Cem Catikkas you are right. Now I iterate through the HashMap and get the element I need. and do whatever it is that I have to with it.

Answer (score 14):

You appear to be confusing the internal resprentation of a HashMap with how the HashMap behaves.  The collections are the same.  Here is a simple test to prove it to you.

```
public static void main(String... args)
                            throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    HashMap<String, Object> fileObj = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    ArrayList<String> cols = new ArrayList<String>();
    cols.add("a");
    cols.add("b");
    cols.add("c");
    fileObj.put("mylist", cols);
    {
        File file = new File("temp");
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
        ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
        s.writeObject(fileObj);
        s.close();
    }
    File file = new File("temp");
    FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);
    HashMap<String, Object> fileObj2 = (HashMap<String, Object>) s.readObject();
    s.close();

    Assert.assertEquals(fileObj.hashCode(), fileObj2.hashCode());
    Assert.assertEquals(fileObj.toString(), fileObj2.toString());
    Assert.assertTrue(fileObj.equals(fileObj2));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe you´re making a common mistake. You forgot to close the stream after using it!

```
 File file = new File("temp");  
 FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);  
 ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);          
 s.writeObject(fileObj);
 s.close();
```

Comment: No. I had closed the stream. I just did not mention it in the code. I have made the edits now.

Comment: Regardless, `f.close()` will not properly close the `ObjectOutputStream`. You should always call close on the uppermost decorated stream, i.e. `s.close()`.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use JSON file to read and write MAP object.

> To write map object into JSON file

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("name", "Suson");
    map.put("age", 26);

    // write JSON to a file
    mapper.writeValue(new File("c:\\myData.json"), map);
```

> To read map object from JSON file

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // read JSON from a file
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(
                new File("c:\\myData.json"),
                new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });

        System.out.println(map.get("name"));
        System.out.println(map.get("age"));
```

and import ObjectMapper from com.fasterxml.jackson and put code in try catch block

Comment: refer this link : https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 1):

Your first line:

```
HashMap<String,Object> fileObj = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```

gave me pause, as the values are not guaranteed to be `Serializable` and thus may not be written out correctly. You should really define the object as a `HashMap<String, Serializable>` (or if you prefer, simpy `Map<String, Serializable>`).

I would also consider serializing the Map in a simple text format such as JSON since you are doing a simple `String -> List<String>` mapping.

Comment: The class itself within which these lines appear is Serializable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're getting what you're saving.  Have you inspected the map before you save it?  In `HashMap`:

```
/**
 * The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.
 */
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 16;
```

e.g. the default `HashMap` will start off with 16 `null`s.  You use one of the buckets, so you only have 15 `null`s left when you save, which is what you get when you load.
Try inspecting `fileObj.keySet()`, `.entrySet()` or `.values()` to see what you expect.

`HashMap`s are designed to be fast while trading off memory.  See [Wikipedia's Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) entry for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Same data if you want to write to a text file

```
public void writeToFile(Map<String, List<String>> failureMessage){
    if(file!=null){
        try{
           BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> map : failureMessage.entrySet()) {
                writer.write(map.getKey()+"\n");
                for(String message:map.getValue()){
                    writer.write(message+"\n");
                }
                writer.write("\n");
            }
            writer.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Unable to write to file: "+file.getPath());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```