# How to read a txt complex hashmap in the most efficient way in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, file

Here is my code to write the hashmap to a txt.

```
//In a previous method:
private Context contexta = MainActivity.this;
writeToFile(my_hashmap.toString(), contexta);
```

Then the method `writeToFile`:

```
private void writeToFile(String data,Context context) {
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("config.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
```

My hashmap `my_hashmap` is built like `hashmap(String, hashmap2(String, hashmap3(String, Integer)))`

So my text file contains:

```
A_string1={{B_string1={C_string1=0, C_string2=0, C_string3=0}, B_string2={...}...}, A_string2={...}, ...
```

What is the most efficient way to read it again from the file?

Important: **I want it to be readable in the .txt !**
So as far as I understood Serialization, it will not work for me as it creates non-readable data. I don't want to change the writeToFile method, just a smart way to code a readFromFile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read and write a HashMap to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347504/how-to-read-and-write-a-hashmap-to-a-file)

Comment: @RupeshAgrawal The solution of the question you linked doesn't suit my needs: The writeObject will create a non-readable file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)); to write file 

and

new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)) to read file

Write to file

```
  File file = new File("filePath");
  FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file);
  ObjectOutputStream s = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
  s.writeObject(fileObj);
  s.close();
```

Read from file

```
    File file = new File("filePath");
FileInputStream f = new FileInputStream(file);
ObjectInputStream s = new ObjectInputStream(f);
HashMap<String, Object> fileObj2 = (HashMap<String, Object>) s.readObject();
```

Comment: But with writeObject the data is non-readable. Isn't there a way to do it with a txt readable file?

Comment: @Artemyx : you can try converting hash map to json and storing json to file and do vise versa for reading from file